# How do I fix my discord bot (in discord.js) not responding to my commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to get my discord bot to work, but it will only become online on discord and say that it's online in the console. What am I doing wrong

here's the code from my index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ], intents: ["GUILDS", /* Other intents... */]});
const token = '(token here)';
client.login(token);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I ARRIVE FROM THE ASHES OF THE EARTH');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'Hello') {
        message.send('I HAVE A GUN');
    }
});
client.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('ZE POPCORN IS DEAD');
});

const prefix = '-'; 
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === prefix + 'ping') {
        message.send('Gun').then(message => message.edit('Pong'));
    }
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === prefix + 'shutdown') {
        if (message.author.id === '262707958646901248') {
            message.send('Shutting down...').then(message => client.destroy());
        }
    }
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        if (command === 'ping') {
            message.send('Gun');
        }
    }
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === prefix + 'help') {
        message.send('figure it out I guess?');
    }
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === prefix + 'info') {
        message.send('I made this bot when popcorn "died". I hope you enjoy it.');
    }
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'ping') {
        message.send('https://tenor.com/view/heavy-tf2-the-rock-rock-the-rock-the-dwayne-johnson-gif-22149531');
    }
});
```

I tried all the commands that I put in and such, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: erm... why do you have like 100 event listeners seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code needs a fair bit of work, primarily in organization. Also please take a minute to get familiar with this entire site as all the different elements of this are here and it is a tool you will use often.

discord v13
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/general/welcome

discord v12
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/general/welcome

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({
    partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"],
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES" /* Other intents... */ ] // make sure GUILD_MESSAGES is in there
});
const prefix = '-';
const token = '(token here)';
client.login(token);

client.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('ZE POPCORN IS DEAD');
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I ARRIVE FROM THE ASHES OF THE EARTH');
});

client.on('message', async message => { // add async
    const content = message.content.toLowerCase() // For readability

    // message.send will not work, it needs to be either message.channel.send() or message.reply()

// these will work without prefix

    if (content === 'hello') {
        message.reply('I HAVE A GUN');
    } else if (content === 'ping') {
        // Below will just send the link
        message.reply('https://tenor.com/view/heavy-tf2-the-rock-rock-the-rock-the-dwayne-johnson-gif-22149531');
        // Below will send the attachment
        message.reply({
            attachments: 'https://tenor.com/view/heavy-tf2-the-rock-rock-the-rock-the-dwayne-johnson-gif-22149531'
        })
    }


// these will require the prefix

    if (content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        if (command === 'ping') {
            message.reply('Gun');
        } else if (command === 'shutdown') {
            if (message.author.id === '262707958646901248') {
                message.reply('Shutting down...').then(() => client.destroy()); // message not used, so not required
            } else {
                message.reply('Not allowed') // added else statement
            }
        } else if (command === 'help') {
            message.reply('figure it out I guess?');
        } else if (command === 'info') {
            message.reply('I made this bot when popcorn "died". I hope you enjoy it.');
        }
    }
});
```